# Regarding file association in ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, default-applications, file-management

I have a Micromax Supercanvas 2 phone.

I installed ES File Explorer from Play Store. I was browsing through various directories and files. When trying to open server logs, events, and other similar files, I was asked to open the file from a list of applications (e.g HTML viewer, ES file viewer, etc.) I selected Android HTML Viewer (as default). No file content is shown. Instead, an error is shown that file does not exist on path.

I tried going through all android apps and removing the cache and defaults. It did not remove the association. It still opens files in HTML Viewer.

Is there any way to remove the association, so that I can select which app to use to open the file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I think ES's default app associations are separate from the operating system's. To clear ES's file associations (assuming you are using the latest version), from ES File explorer go to *Settings > Cleanup setting > Clear defaults*.

The next time you try to open a  file ES File explorer should now ask which application you want to open the file with.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [Default App Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager). From the app's description:

> Default App Manager is a simple yet very functional app to manage (set defaults, clear/reset defaults) default applications for different types of actions that Android does. Unlike other applications that allow you to manage defaults for only one-two types of categories, this app allows to you to manage for almost all the common actions.

The description sounds quite promising. But not having tried the app myself, I cannot give any guarantee it will solve your special issue ;)